# Inhomogeneous Boundary Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following BVP

$a V^{\prime \prime}(x) + b[c - x]V^{\prime}(x) + x V(x) = 0$

with the boundary conditions

$V(-\infty) = 0 \quad \mbox{and} \quad V(0) = 1$

I tried some standard approaches but nothing worked.

However - Plugging into mathematica I get something in terms of hermite polynomials and hypergeometric functions which I've verified numerically for some parameters $a,b,c$ .

Can someone suggest whether titis is actually solvable ?

Comment: Do you know anything about your constants? Also, where is $d$ coming in? I can't see it in the differential equation. In the end, the general solution to the differential equation is expressible in terms of generalized Hermite polynomials and hypergeometric functions. There is nothing to do about that unless one has specific parameters. It could be an idea to look up the asymptotics of these functions as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: sorry no $d$ that was a typo. 

I know the constants are all positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the meaning of this question, $a\neq0$ and $b\neq0$ should be restricted

Hint:

Let $V(x)=\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds$ ,

Then $a(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)''+b(c-x)(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)'+x\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_C(as^2+bcs)e^{xs}K(s)~ds-\int_C(bs-1)e^{xs}K(s)~d(xs)=0$

$\int_C(as^2+bcs)e^{xs}K(s)~ds-\int_C(bs-1)K(s)~d(e^{xs})=0$

$\int_C(as^2+bcs)e^{xs}K(s)~ds-[(bs-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_C+\int_Ce^{xs}~d((bs-1)K(s))=0$

$\int_C(as^2+bcs)e^{xs}K(s)~ds-[(bs-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_C+\int_C((bs-1)K'(s)+bK(s))e^{xs}~ds=0$

$\int_C((bs-1)K'(s)+(as^2+bcs+b)K(s))e^{xs}~ds-[(bs-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_C=0$

$\therefore(bs-1)K'(s)+(as^2+bcs+b)K(s)=0$

$(bs-1)K'(s)=-((as+bc)s+b)K(s)$

$\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}=-\dfrac{\left(a\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+\dfrac{a}{b}+bc\right)s+b}{bs-1}$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=-\int\dfrac{as\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+\dfrac{(a+b^2c)s}{b}+b}{bs-1}ds$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=-\int\dfrac{as\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+\dfrac{a+b^2c}{b}\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+\dfrac{a+b^2c}{b^2}+b}{bs-1}ds$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=-\int\left(\dfrac{as}{b}+\dfrac{a+b^2c}{b^2}+\dfrac{a+b^3+b^2c}{b^2(bs-1)}\right)ds$

$\ln K(s)=-\dfrac{as^2}{2b}-\dfrac{(a+b^2c)s}{b^2}-\dfrac{a+b^3+b^2c}{b^3}\ln\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)+c_1$

$K(s)=C\left(s-\dfrac{1}{b}\right)^{-\frac{a+b^3+b^2c}{b^3}}e^{-\frac{as^2}{2b}-\frac{(a+b^2c)s}{b^2}}$

Comment: thanks for the very clear exposition. The constant C can then be obtained from V(0) = 1 -> So the area under K(s) has to sum to 1. Reduction of order then gives me a second solution for which second boundary condition is imposed.